# Dataview rowfilter has message AgreedToDisclaimer='True' AND Deleted = 'false'

Tags: c#, asp.net

who can explain for me the message `"AgreedToDisclaimer='True' AND Deleted = 'false'" of Rowfilter option in Dataview`.

```
DataView view = new DataView(set.Tables[0], "AgreedToDisclaimer='True' 
  AND Deleted = 'false'", string.Empty, DataViewRowState.OriginalRows);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, from the [DataView constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa325683%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) :

```
public DataView(
   DataTable table,
   string RowFilter,
   string Sort,
   DataViewRowState RowState
);
```

> RowFilter :
>       A RowFilter to apply to the DataView.

`RowFilter` is used for filter the data that will be displayed.
In your example :

> "AgreedToDisclaimer='True' AND Deleted = 'false'"

means the dataview will display the row that have AgreedToDisclaimer column value equals true and Deleted column value is false.

More : [DataView.RowFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.rowfilter%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)